DBMS_JOB.SUBMIT with INSERT statement
I am trying to implement the process with DBMS_JOB.SUBMIT with an INSERT statement but I am not able to successfully transfer the data from one table to another.
DECLARE
    l_job NUMBER;
 BEGIN
    DBMS_JOB.SUBMIT(
       job       => l_job,
       what      => 'BEGIN insert into customers_tbl1 select * from customers_tbl; 
 END;'--,
     --  next_date => SYSDATE--, -- Schedule for 1 hour from now
       --interval  => 'SYSDATE'   -- Reschedule every day
    );
   COMMIT; -- Important to commit the transaction to schedule the job
 END;

Table Data:
    CREATE TABLE customers_tbl 
    ( customer_id number(10),
      customer_name varchar2(50),
      city varchar2(50)
    );
    insert into customers_tbl(customer_id,customer_name,city) values(1,'Albert','Munich');
    insert into customers_tbl(customer_id,customer_name,city) values(2,'Alex','Stuttgart');
    insert into customers_tbl(customer_id,customer_name,city) values(3,'Sasuke','Tokyo');
    
    CREATE TABLE customers_tbl1 
    ( customer_id number(10),
      customer_name varchar2(50),
      city varchar2(50)
    );


When using DBMS_SCHEDULER:
BEGIN
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
        job_name        => 'MT_TEST1',
        job_type        => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
        job_action      => 'BEGIN insert into customers_tbl1 (CUSTOMER_ID, CUSTOMER_NAME, CITY) select CUSTOMER_ID, CUSTOMER_NAME, CITY from customers_tbl; END;',
        start_date      => SYSTIMESTAMP,
        repeat_interval => 'FREQ=SECONDLY;INTERVAL=10',
        enabled         => TRUE,
        comments        => NULL
    );
END;
/


The what parameter needs a proper PL/SQL block (BEGIN ... END;) and terminates the INSERT statement with a semicolon.
Corrected Code:
DECLARE
    l_job NUMBER;
BEGIN
    DBMS_JOB.SUBMIT(
        job       => l_job,
        what      => 'BEGIN insert into customers_tbl1 select * from customers_tbl; END;',
        next_date => SYSDATE,       -- Schedule for immediate execution
        interval  => SYSDATE + 1    -- Repeats daily
    );
    COMMIT; -- Commit the transaction to schedule the job
END;
/

You can use SYSDATE + 1/24 in next_date if you want to schedule for one hour from now.
Verify if data is transferred or not:
SELECT * FROM customers_tbl1;

Monitor your job status:
SELECT job, what, next_date, broken
FROM user_jobs;


I have the following problem after your fixes Superman:    END;
Error report -
ORA-27465: invalid value 30-SEP-24 for attribute REPEAT_INTERVAL
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_ISCHED", line 9381
ORA-00904: "SEP": invalid identifier
ORA-27420: Following  message from ICAL interval interpreter
ORA-27415: repeat interval or calendar must start with a frequency clause
ORA-06512: at line 4
27465. 00000 -  "invalid value %s for attribute %s"
*Cause:    An invalid value was provided for the specified attribute.
*Action:   Reissue the command using a valid value for this attribute.

What is your database set to use, DBMS_SCHEDULER or DBMS_JOB? Both use different syntaxes.

That's it DBMS_SCHEDULER

@Bob then you need to schedule a job using DBMS_SCHEDULE, not DBMS_JOB. Use start_date parameter with SYSTIMESTAMP and repeat_interval as null or as per your need.

Thank you!
Superman.Does this look good to you?
still not working.

BEGIN
DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
job_name         =>  'MT_TEST1',
job_type         =>  'PLSQL_BLOCK',
job_action       =>  'begin  insert into customers_tbl1
value(CUSTOMER_ID,CUSTOMER_NAME,CITY) select
CUSTOMER_ID,CUSTOMER_NAME,CITY from customers_tbl; end;',
repeat_interval  =>  'FREQ=SECONDLY;INTERVAL=10',
--job_style        => 'LIGHTWEIGHT',
enabled          =>  true,
comments         => null);
END;

exec dbms_scheduler.run_job('mt_test1');

@Bob I have posted it as an answer you can check. If it works well, please accept it as an answer :)

@supermen         These 2 functions solve the problem for me
alter system set job_queue_processes=13 scope=memory;
alter system set max_dump_file_size = unlimited scope=memory;
